Errors during updates (key issue)
So I have updated my system and sources list only to get errors during apt update about the keyring. I have attempted to restore the keystores  with success excluding one key. Here is a list of the output when running apt update.
# sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 https:// download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http:// ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:3 http:// archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]
Hit:4 https:// repo.cubecoders.com debian/ InRelease
Hit:5 https:// packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease
Get:6 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:7 http:// archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [109 kB]
Get:8 http:// archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Err:3 http:// archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Hit:9 https:// repo.45drives.com/debian focal InRelease
Err:7 http:// archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Err:6 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Err:8 http:// archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http:// archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
E: The repository 'http:// archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http:// archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
E: The repository 'http:// archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
W: GPG error: http:// archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
E: The repository 'http:// archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

I've attempted to pull the key again but to no avail.
# gpg --keyserver hkps://keys.openpgp.org --recv-keys 871920D1991BC93C
# gpg --keyid-format long --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 871920D1991BC93C
# curl -fsSL https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x871920D1991BC93C | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/keyrings/ubuntu-security.gpg

This is running the following:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
If you need other information, please let me know.
NOTE: Due to my being a new member here I had to put spaces in the links and command output due to links being there even though they are public ubuntu archives and keystores.
